# Return data from SQL based on user input without reloading form - Classic ASP

Tags: javascript, sql-server, asp-classic, bootstrap-modal

I am working on adding a new feature to an existing Classic ASP application. In this feature the user will scan a bar-code which will input its value into a text field in a form within a bootstrap modal. The scanner is configured to send a TAB as well after the data.

What I need is a way to query the database on field exit and populate other fields in the modal with data from the query that is based on the scanned value. I need to do this without reloading the page or closing the modal so the user can verify this information and make changes before saving the form.

What is the best way to do this? I have no issue writing the SP, but do not have any idea how to call it and then return it's values. Can I possibly use JavaScript/PHP for this?

Comment: Yes, that's arguably the most common task JS is used for these days. The backend technology has nothing to do with it, it could be whatever server side language you are comfortable with. Start here: https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: I ended up finding this really helpful article after restructuring my Google search: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/98/ajax-with-classic-asp-using-jquery I used the JSON option.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use some ajax

https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Basically you would send a request to your .asp script which will run the stored procedure then send a response using `Response.Write`.

Then parse that response in jquery.

Unlike ASP Classic, AJAX is a new technology so it works better with JSON.

There aren't many JSON libraries

You can use json2.asp:

https://github.com/nagaozen/asp-xtreme-evolution/blob/master/lib/axe/classes/Parsers/json2.asp

Or if you want you can try it XML, but its unpopular these days and more tedious to parse.

You mentionned PHP, that's not a bad idea because, it's all built in for you see:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Hope this helps